# Lai Fa - beautiful flower?

Tags: meaning

My girlfriend is adopted into a Chinese family and they gave her the middle name "Lai Fa". Her mother is Cantonese and says it means beautiful flower.

But when we google the words online nothing comes up. Is there an origin of this term?

Comment: Chinese names are great! I know a guy, his given name （名） is 飞龙， 'flying dragon' and a girl called 龙雨。  How cool is that！ Much more interesting than Western names. I also knew a girl called 马成柳，'horse become a willow'!

Comment: Actually there are many English cool names, like Moneymaker, Fairchild, kissinger...

Comment: 哈哈 Kissinger, that old devil! The name derives from Old High German kisil, modern German Kiesel, a pebble, 砾石. Not nearly as nice as Chinese names

Comment: cf.  http://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=kissinger
Kissinger Name Meaning
    German and Jewish (from Germany): habitational name from Kissingen in Franconia or Kissing in Bavaria, both of which, according to Bahlow, are named with a lost element kis(s) ‘marsh’, ‘swamp’, although Berger favors a Slavic origin, from kisac ‘to make acid’.

Comment: Kissinger means "German and Jewish"? Really? Berger favours? Does he know? Bahlow lost an element? Do you have any leads on the lost element? Maybe they mixed up kis- with slei: O.Ice. slīkr “ smooth “, slīkisteinn grindstone, whetstone”, O.H.G. slīhhan ‘slink” (= “glide, slide”), sleihha “loop, sled “, M.L.G. slīk , slick , M.H.G. slich ‘schlick, slime, mud”; participle *slihta- “geglättet” in Goth. slaíhts ‘schlicht, eben”, O.Ice. slēttr “ smooth, eben, straight”, O.H.G. slëht ‘straight, eben, evil, bad”, Ger. schlicht and schlecht , O.E. sliht , M.Eng. slight , sleght “ smooth, eben”;

Comment: Reference says name derives from "Kissingen" or "Kissing" and then explains origin of the names of latter localities. There are o.c. many other Jewish (German) " habitational" names. Regarding Kissingen also see Wikipedia (The town was first documented in the year 801 as chizzicha). For possible Slavic origin of Kissingen note earlier settlement of region.
Anyhow are there any references for derivation of "Kissinger" from "kisil", what would be the connection with "Kissingen" then? Quoted experts admit uncertainty of origin of place name "Kissingen" while Gangosa knows that of "Kissinger" ?

Comment: regarding etymology of place name Kissingen note more info in German version of Wikipedia article: "Die Herkunft des Ortsnamens Kissingen ist in der Geschichtsforschung nahezu ungeklärt. Das Zugehörigkeitssuffix „-ing“, das die Abhängigkeit einer Siedlung von einem Lehnsherrn oder Ähnlichem bezeichnet, ist in diesem Ortsnamen sekundär. Eine konsequente Schreibung mit der Endung findet sich erst ab dem 18. Jahrhundert. Möglicherweise besteht der erste Namensteil aus dem keltischen Personennamen „Citus“, der durch das keltische Suffix „acum“ abgeleitet wurde."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **麗**  http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1152/
>
> lai6   (jyutping)
>
> (1) [adj] **beautiful**; magnificent; elegant

~

> **花** http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/32/
>
> faa1   (jyutping)
>
> (1) [n] **flower**; blossom

Your girlfriend's middle name is 麗花 (lai6 faa1 in Cantonese jyutping)

*if you want to search Cantonese words, [CantoDict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/) is the place to go*